# Is it possible to Always Allow the permission for camera and microphone third-party Apps using Cordova in iOS?

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios, ios-permissions

I've created the VideoConferning App for Using Webrtc, and also made the app for using Cordova in ios, but the issue was when I opened the app, each time it triggers the permissions for the camera and microphone.
*here are my plugins*

```
cordova-plugin-camera 6.0.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-file 7.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 5.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 6.1.0 "Media"
cordova-plugin-network-information 3.0.0 "Network Information"
```

*cordova ios Platform Version;*

```
Installed platforms:
  ios 6.2.0
```

Ref Image

[image]

**how to modify the always allow for that permissions?**

Comment: Use this plugin to check and request permission `https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic`

Comment: @RaviAshara I've Tried this but not work, that problem was every time the review on the in-app browser detected the camera and microphone, for your reference I've added image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i found the solution for this every time ask permission for cordova ios webview

Add this Function on CDVWebViewUIDelegate.m

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView requestMediaCapturePermissionForOrigin:(WKSecurityOrigin *)origin initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame type:(WKMediaCaptureType)type decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKPermissionDecision))decisionHandler API_AVAILABLE(ios(15.0)) API_AVAILABLE(ios(15.0)){  decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecisionGrant);
    
}
```